# Application Loader: No Eligible Software

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, coronasdk, application-loader

I uploaded an app to iTunes Connect December 2014 no problem. Reskinned the app and attempted to upload the nearly identical code in Feb 2015 with the Application Loader error: "No eligible software found. Make sure this software is owned by your developer organization".

Confused, I attempted to reupload the original app, which now gives the same error.

I understand Apple's Feb 1st iOS 8 and 64-bit update, and have been using an updated SDK (Corona 2015.2545). Full specs: Yos 10.10.2 (14C109), Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), and Application Loader 3.

In attempts to solve I've:

1. Uninstalled / Reinstalled XCode, Application Loader, Corona
2. Ensured all certificates / provision profiles are active and reflect the correct ID
3. Downloaded previous versions of Application Loader, to no effect
4. Adjusted minOS in Corona build.settings
5. Ensured correct account login & match with iTunes connect, Xcode, and Application Loader.

The app works perfectly on Android, it's just uploading to iTunes which seems to be the problem.

If anyone has thoughts on what to try next, it'd be greatly appreciated. If there are any work arounds to Application Loader which have worked for you, I'd appreciate that too :)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Open up your keychain settings and ensure you don't have any old, expired or duplicate entries for your developer account.

Comment: Thank you for the support Sandy! I've just tried removing all keys, revoking all certs, and reattempting with a clean slate and restart.

Still no luck. I'm sorry I don't have the ability to upvote yet, but thank you for the response regardless.